# Angular 6 - ngModel establish two way data binding via function

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular6

Given an array of people:

```
let people = [...]
```

I want to write in Angular a dropdown where you select a person from a list and dynamically change their name from a generated input box.

I have the following snippet of code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="personIndex">
    <option *ngFor="let p of people" [value]="findIndexOfPerson(p.id)">
      {{p.name}}
    </option>
</select>

<input placeholder="Name" 
       [ngModel]="getPersonName()"
       [hidden]="personIndex == null">
```

Within my component:

```
personIndex = null;

findIndexOfPerson(i) {
    return this.people.findIndex(p => p.id == i) 
}

getPersonName() {
    if (this.personIndex == null || this.personIndex == -1) return null;
    return this.people[this.personIndex]['name'];
}
```

Now *I do understand* that I cannot establish a two way data binding with a getter function using [ngModel]. On that note if I change

> [ngModel]="getPersonName()" to [(ngModel)]="getPersonName()"

the program throws a compiler error.

So the question is how can I get what I want? How can I change the logic to allow my people list to be changed using a dropdown and input box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing a function that will change the name on change in the input value. You should listen to the `keyup` event on the `input` and call this method with `$event.target.value`:

```
changeNameOfCurrentlySelectedPerson(newName) {
  if(this.personIndex) {
    this.people[this.personIndex].name = newName;
  }
}
```

This will check if a person is selected from the dropdown and change the name accordingly.

Here's how you'll bind it in your view:

```
<input 
  placeholder="Name" 
  [ngModel]="getPersonName()"
  (keyup)="changeNameOfCurrentlySelectedPerson($event.target.value)"
  [hidden]="personIndex == null">
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-likkpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Even though it doesn't sound efficient this is an excellent answer. Thanks

Comment: You could use `change` instead of `keyup` but that would only work after you blur from your input. But you wanted it two-ways. Hence I suggested `keyup`

Answer (score 1):

Use `[ngValue]` to bind a person in select. Use that person to bind to other properties of the person. You won't need any methods for this.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson">
  <option selected [ngValue]="null">Select a person</option>
  <option 
    *ngFor="let person of people; let i = index" 
    [ngValue]="person">
    {{person.name}}
  </option>
</select>

<input 
  placeholder="Name" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson.name"
  *ngIf="selectedPerson">
```

---

```
export class MyComponent {
  people = [....];
  selectedPerson = null;
}
```

Also, even if you wanted to find index in `*ngFor`, you can use `let i = index`

ie. `<option *ngFor="let p of people; let i = index" [value]="i">`

Comment: I want the people array to dynamically change, in this example will the input value change the select form options in real time?

Comment: `{{person.name}}` will obviously change. So as you type in the name, it will be changed in the select option.